# Lining things up while using columns

Tags: html, semantic-web, tableless

I have a request that may not be possible.

I'd like to line up the elements of a form so that the inputs all start at the same place:

```
Name:                            [                           ]
Company:                         [                           ]
Some question with a long name: [                           ]
```

But my list is (somewhat) long and I would like to show them in multiple columns on screens that are wide enough.

Ideally, I'd find a POSH method (table-free is semantically appropriate, I think) that works on a reasonable number of browsers.

My current page uses a table.  I tried CSS with

```
columns: auto; 
-moz-column-count: auto; 
-moz-column-width: auto; 
-webkit-column-count: auto; 
-webkit-column-width: auto;
```

but Firefox (at least) won't break a table across columns.

Comment: [In the future there may be an easy way to do this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CSS `display: inline-block` would be the best way to do it. Depending on your browser compatibility needs, you may need to use some workarounds since it is only supported in modern browsers consistently.

A List Apart has a good article about how to use the `inline-block` setting: [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms).

Then, to get some parts to wrap or not, just use the usual word breaking/non-breaking `&nbsp;` or `width: ...` specifications.

Answer (score -1):

I would use JavaScript and the JQuery library with regular HTML tables to:

-First, calculate the width in pixels of the column (This gives you the freedom to update the list without having to worry about updating and measuring pixels every time) Ex, widthOfQuestion + widthOfInput.
   -Second, find the resolution that is being used (Or the browser width - preferable).
   -Third, see if double the width of the column could fit on their resolution. If so, then write in '\n '.

To specifically know how to do this, consult StackOverflow.